# Get rows of a Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm working on a RadGrid, and I want to access its rows but it seems it does not have a `.Rows` property.

Here's what I have tried until now:

[image]

How can I access `rgCustomers`'s Rows collection? I want to add a button to each row.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Telerik's documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-data-items.html),

"Each dynamic row in the grid represents a record from the specified data source. Dynamic rows are represented by the GridDataItem class (a descendent of GridItem).

Each GridTableView has a set of rows (the Items collection) of type GridDataItem."

So you want to use the Items collection of the grid, which is a collection of GridDataItems.

```
protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  rgCustomers.DataSource = odsCustomers;
  rgCustomers.DataBind();
  foreach (GridDataItem row in rgCustomers.Items)
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming it's WPF/Silverlight RadGrid?

If You want to access row control in databound grid  (not row data) - You'll have to use ItemContainerGenerator property of RadGrid. For example:

```
rgCustomers.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
```

or

```
rgCustomers.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(odsCustomers[0]);
```

will return first row control (of type RadGridViewRow if I remember correctly)

Comment: Should I do the same if I want to iterate through rows?

Comment: I'm using Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid

Comment: Ahh, it's Asp.net control. My solution is WPF/Silverlight based. Sorry, I don't know much about Web controls.

Answer (score 1):

#### - If you want to add a button on every row:

*GridTemplateColumn* or *GridButtonColumn* will do the trick.

#### - If you want to access the current row:

1. Use the OnClick event handler of the button.

   ```
   <telerik:RadButton ID="BTN_DEMO" runat="server" HeaderText="N°1 DEMO BTN"
   Text='<%#"Click Me iM N°"+((IhateEvalDataSource) Container.DataItem).Stuff_ID %>' 
   OnClick="BTN_DEMO_Click"></telerik:RadButton>
   ```
2. Get a reference to the GridDataItem using (sender as RadButton).NamingContainer.

   ```
   protected void BTN_BL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       GridDataItem G = ((RadButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridDataItem;
   }
   ```
3. Use [GetDataKeyValue() method](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/rows/accessing-cells-and-rows#accessing-raw-field-data-and-key-values) to extract the record ID:

   ```
   DEMO_INT = (int)G.GetDataKeyValue("mySweetInt"); 
   DEMO_STRING = (string)G.GetDataKeyValue("MyString");
   ```