# How to Show Total Row Count of a Telerik Radgrid - JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik

How Can I get total rows of a Tekerik Radgrid?

I saw [Get rows of a Telerik RadGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807646/get-rows-of-a-telerik-radgrid) but in my case I use JS/jQuery when loads the page.

I have a Telerik:RadGrid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gvLotes"> ... </telerik:RadGrid>
```

In my case `size`, `lenght` and `val` don't work. Someone has idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var grid = $find("<%= gvLotes.ClientID %>"); 
 var rowCount = grid.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems().length;
```

This is what you need to get total rows on the client side using JavaScript.

Please check following link for more details on available client-side methods for RadGrid.

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/client-side-programming/gridtableview-object/gridtableview-class-members

Hope it helps.

Comment: this gives the number of items in the current page

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
var dataSource = grid.dataSource; 

var totalRecords = dataSource.total();
```

Comment: what is kendoGrid here?  Is that a constant?